# Как отдалить текст вводимый пользователем в тег <input>?

Tags: html, css

Мне надо сделать так чтобы текст вводимый пользователем в тег  был отдалён на 17px от левого края я не понимаю как это сделать.Помогите

Comment: Может, `padding-left: 17px;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте инпуту padding-left: 17px

Comment: это сработало  но все инпуты перекосились

Comment: @АртёмЛукичёв, что значит "перекосились"?

Comment: спасибо за ответ